# Find group of words in a text file and extract the line to new text file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

my file **ref.txt** contains word "hi" "hello" "aloha" as per below:

```
hi
hello
aloha
```

And I have one more file **abc.txt** which contains many words including the above 3 words.

Now I developed a powershell batch to search the worlds in **abc.txt** and extract the line containing the words to a new file **done.txt**. i use *-match* command to find the word.

How to use the file **ref.txt** which contains the words for the finding, instead of declare the words in coding? Its fine if its in *cmd.exe* or *powershell* coding. Kindly enlighten me.

```
$source = "C:\temp\abc.txt"  
$destination = "C:\temp\done.txt"
$hits = select-string -Path $source -SimpleMatch "hi","hello","aloha"  
$filecontents = get-content $source
foreach($hit in $hits) { 
    $filecontents[$hit.linenumber-1]| out-file -append 
    $destination "" |out-file -append $destination    
 }
```

Comment: I don't see how a SimpleMatch helps you. I don't think you want "hi" to match "hill". I suspect you only want to match whole words.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your question, you want to use the words in ref.txt as search criteria, so that if you have a file abc.txt that contains these words, the lines containing the words will be returned in a file done.txt.  This can be accomplished simply in cmd.exe in one of a few ways.

```
findstr /g:ref.txt abc.txt > done.txt
```

The above solution would return any line that contains any of the words (even if they are in a sentence or part of another word, such as hi and high), but would not be case insensitive.

```
/R - Use regex
/I - Case insensitive search
/B - Match at the beginning of the line only
/E - Match at the end of the line only
```

So if you only wanted to match words in the file and not match a word in the sentence, you could do 
`findstr /BE /g:ref.txt abc.txt > done.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell command `get-content`

It will get you a string that you can split on `\n` to get each line separately.

```
PS C:\> get-content c:\ref.txt
hi
hello
aloha
```

Split it and save in an array. Then perform action of your choice for each item by using

```
foreach ($element in $array) 
{ 
     /your code here/ 
}
```

You can find more information [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.02.powershell.aspx).

If you want to use all three words together for search match, just replace the `\n` with `,` and place in your command after `-SimpleMatch`

Answer (score 0):

OLd question, but it bubbled up...

The `ref.txt` file can be used to construct the regular expression used by the `-Pattern` parameter of [Select-String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7). The `Line` property of the resulting [MatchInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) objects can then be piped to [Set-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-5.1).

```
$WordList    = '.\ref.txt'
$Source      = '.\abc.txt'
$Destination = '.\done.txt'

$Pattern     = '(^|\W)' + (( Get-Content $WordList) -join '(\W|$)|(^|\W)' ) + '(\W|$)'

Select-String $Pattern $Source |
    Select -Expand Line |
       Set-Content $Destination
```

With the contents of `abc.txt` being:

```
bob
hi mom
Carol
well hello world
Ted
In Hawaii, we say aloha
Alice
"Hill" should not be matched
```

We get:

```
PS C:\...\Custom Word Search>$WordList    = '.\ref.txt'
>> $Source      = '.\abc.txt'
>> $Destination = '.\done.txt'
>>
>> $Pattern     = '(^|\W)' + ( (Get-Content $WordList) -join '(\W|$)|(^|\W)' ) + '(\W|$)'
>>
>> Select-String $Pattern $Source |
>>     Select -Expand Line |
>>        Set-Content $Destination
>>
PS C:\...\Custom Word Search>Get-Content .\done.txt
hi mom
hello world
In Hawaii, we say aloha
PS C:\...\Custom Word Search>
```